# Batch Recursively Launch Specific .exe

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

In windows I have a batch file, named the same as a folder in its current directory.

I am trying to recursively launch a specific `.exe` file that is a few folders deep in the above mentioned folder.

I am trying:

```
set "NAME=DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe"
for /R "%~n0\" %%I in ("%NAME%") do if exist "%%I" start "" /WAIT "%%I"
```

But that is trying to launch `DRAGON.exe`, then `QUEST.exe`, then `XI.exe` then `S.exe` and I don't understand why.

I think it will have something to do with quotes, but have tried adding/removing them from everywhere I could see and no luck.

Adding a wildcard to `("%NAME%*")` works, but could be troublesome if there is more than one `.exe` that starts with `DRAGON`.

Comment: If the set in the round brackets of command __FOR__ contains neither `*` nor `?` the command __FOR__ does __not__ search for a file with the specified file name in this case recursively in all folders of specified folder. It does instead assign each full folder path to the specified loop variable concatenated with the specified file name with the double quotes. That was detected by you and so you are using `if exist "%%I"`. But that results for example in `"%%I"` expanding to `if exist "C:\Temp\Test\"DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe""` which is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: There can be used the following command line: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dpn0\DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do "%%I"` There is executed by __FOR__ now one more `cmd.exe` in background to run its internal command __DIR__ to search in subdirectory with name of batch file in directory of the batch file and all its subdirectories for a file with name `DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe` and all the found executables are executed one after the other by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file with waiting for self-termination of the started executable before continuation of __FOR__ loop.

Comment: If only one `DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe` should be found ever in the subdirectory with name of batch file in batch file directory and the executable is a Windows GUI game, it would be better to use: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dpn0\DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do start "" "%%I" & exit /B` The first found `DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe` is started as separate process and next `cmd.exe` exits the processing of the batch file. `exit /B` can be replaced by `goto Label` if the batch file should do more after starting the game as separate parallel running process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have encountered is caused by something that I consider a terrible design flaw of the `for /R` loop and expansion of its meta-variable together with the `~`-modifiers.

Create the following batch file and execute it:

```cmd
@for /R "%~dp0." %%I in (foo bar "foo bar" "foo bar?") do @(
    echo/
    echo Modifier '~nx': %%~nxI
    echo No modifiers  : %%I
    echo Modifier '~'  : %%~I
    echo Modifier '~f' : %%~fI
    echo '~' and quoted: "%%~I"
)
```

The output will be this, given that there are two files `foo bar` and `foo barS` available in the directory of the batch file:

> ```cmd
> Modifier '~nx': foo
> No modifiers  : D:\test dir\foo
> Modifier '~'  : D:\test dir\foo
> Modifier '~f' : D:\test dir\foo
> '~' and quoted: "D:\test dir\foo"
>
> Modifier '~nx': bar
> No modifiers  : D:\test dir\bar
> Modifier '~'  : D:\test dir\bar
> Modifier '~f' : D:\test dir\bar
> '~' and quoted: "D:\test dir\bar"
>
> Modifier '~nx': "foo bar"
> No modifiers  : D:\test dir\"foo bar"
> Modifier '~'  : D:\test dir\"foo bar"
> Modifier '~f' : D:\test dir\"foo bar"
> '~' and quoted: "D:\test dir\"foo bar""
>
> Modifier '~nx': foo bar
> No modifiers  : D:\test dir\foo bar
> Modifier '~'  : D:\test dir\foo bar
> Modifier '~f' : D:\test dir\foo bar
> '~' and quoted: "D:\test dir\foo bar"
>
> Modifier '~nx': foo barS
> No modifiers  : D:\test dir\foo barS
> Modifier '~'  : D:\test dir\foo barS
> Modifier '~f' : D:\test dir\foo barS
> '~' and quoted: "D:\test dir\foo barS"
> ```

It seems that the `~`-modifiers (which remove potential surrounding quotation marks) are applied too late, namely after preceding an iterated item with the absolute root path. A standard `for` loop does not precede anything, so the problem cannot arise and the `~`-modifiers may see a quoted string (remove `/R "%~dp0."` from the batch file, run it again from its parent directory and check quotation in the output).

The line that reflects our situation is the one `'~' and quoted: "D:\test dir\"foo bar""`; due to its wrong quotation, the command parser unintentionally recognises two different tokens `"D:\test dir\"foo` and `bar""` in the expanded value of `"%%~I"`.

---

To return to your code, there are the following options to work around the bad behaviour of `for /R`:

1. Append a wildcard (best to use `?` since it matches just a single character and therefore reduces the chance of matching unwanted items) and then recheck the name of the iterated item:

   ```cmd
   set "NAME=DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe"
   for /R "%~n0" %%I in ("%NAME%?") do (
       if /I "%%~nxI"=="%NAME%" (
           if exist "%%I" (
               ECHO start "" /WAIT "%%I"
           )
       )
   )
   ```
2. Let `dir /S` return the matching file(s) and use `for /F` to process its output:

   ```cmd
   set "NAME=DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe"
   for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /S /B /A:-D-H-S "%~n0\%NAME%"') do (
       if exist "%%I" (
           ECHO start "" /WAIT "%%I"
       )
   )
   ```

Comment: Thanks, all solutions posted seem to work, however I forgot to mention one point.
The exe can sometimes be in the root of the game folder. eg "DRAGON QUEST XI S\DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe"
The solution mentioned all work if the exe is deeper.

Comment: Well, both `for /R` and `dir /S` search in the root directory as well. How do you call your script? What is the name of the batch script?

Comment: I went with option 2. from @aschipfl.
however I did edit it slightly to cd into the game folder.
`@echo off
set "NAME=DRAGON QUEST XI S.exe"
cd "%~n0"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /S /B /A:-D-H-S "%NAME%"') do (
    if exist "%%I" (
    start "" /WAIT "%%I"
    )
)`
exit